# Grails sessonFactory is null in controller

Tags: hibernate, grails

I've used `sessionFactory` in a service. But when I try to use it in a controller, it says `sessionFactory` is null.

```
class UserMetaDataController{

   def sessionFactory

   def index() {
      def s = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();//ERROR SessionFactory is null
   }
}
```

Comment: typical grails. I cleaned and flushed everything and recompiling made the null error vanish.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get session just use `session` it's a regular that can be used in gsp or in controllers.

Comment: That's how to get an HTTP session. But the question is about getting a hibernate session factory.